# Uploading duplicates but not sure why

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I have the following lines of code, which are supposed to retrieve all documents and images in a PouchDB.
In this case, only two documents with an image each for testing.

When I retrieve all documents from PouchDB I get each document fine. Then it's supposed to upload the image for each document separately and push the return into `$scope.qc.images` before posting `$scope.qc`. But in my case, it's posting document1 twice.

The first post has `document1` with image from `document1`. The second post has `document1` with images from `document1` and `document2`. However, `document2` is never posted.

I would like to post one document with one image each in this test case. Please note the alert in `lastTask`, here I get the same document twice :(

Please see code below:

```
 /**
     * Upload offline qcs
     */
    $scope.uploadOfflineQcs = function () {
      var token = window.localStorage.getItem('yourTokenKey');
      $scope.localQcDB.allDocs({
        include_docs: true
      }).then(function (response) {
        response.rows.forEach(function (row) {
          //this gives me each doc fine
          alert(JSON.stringify(row.doc.qc));
          //this gives me each image fine
          alert(JSON.stringify(row.doc.images));

          $scope.qc = row.doc.qc;
          $scope.images.test = row.doc.images;

          $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Uploading QC...',
            showBackdrop: false
          });

          var promises = $scope.images.test.map(function (image) {
            var options = {
              fileKey: "image",
              fileName: "test.png",
              chunkedMode: true,
              mimeType: "image/png",
              headers: {'x-auth-token': token},
              params: {'questionId': image.questionId}
            };
            return $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(MOBILEAPP_URL + "file/upload", image.image, options);
          });

          return $q.all(promises).then(lastTask); // returns a promise for results

          function lastTask(results) {
            //this gives me same doc which is also uploaded twice.
            alert(JSON.stringify($scope.qc));

            results.forEach(function (result) {
              $scope.qc.image.push(JSON.parse(result.response));

              $scope.qc.coordinates = {
                "latitude": window.localStorage.getItem('latitude'),
                "longitude": window.localStorage.getItem('longitude')
              };

              $http({
                method: 'POST', url: MOBILEAPP_URL + 'api/forms/qualitycontrol', headers: {
                  'x-auth-token': token
                }, data: $scope.qc
              }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  // this callback will be called asynchronously
                  // when the response is available
                  $scope.qc = {image: []};
                  $scope.sigImg = '';
                  $scope.images.test.length = 0;
                  $scope.images.length = 0;
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                  // or server returns response with an error status.
                  $scope.showAlert('error ' + status);
                }).finally(function () {
                  // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
                  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                });
            });
            return results; // keeping the promise chain useful
          }
        });
      }).then(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.showAlert('QC successfully saved!');
        $scope.localQcDB.destroy().then(function () {
          $scope.localQcDB = new PouchDB("offline_qcs");
        }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but you don't appear to be using promises correctly. I recommend reading this article: ["We have a problem with promises"](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).

Two hints to help clean up your promise usage:

1. Angular's `$http` supports both the old style (`.success` and `.error`) as well as the new, promisey style (`.then` and `.catch`). Use the promisey style.
2. Don't use `forEach`; use `return Promise.all(myList.map(...))`.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: I'm actually tying the example from the link, right below "The TLDR of all this is that forEach()/for/while are not the constructs you're looking for. You want Promise.all():" and cant console.log(arrayOfResults), why?

Answer (score 0):

So the following code got everything working fine.

```
 /**
     * Upload offline qcs
     */
    $scope.uploadOfflineQcs = function () {
      var token = window.localStorage.getItem('yourTokenKey');
      $scope.localQcDB.allDocs({
        include_docs: true
      }).
        then(function (result) {
        var rows = result.rows.map(function (row) {
          var images = row.doc.images.map(function (image) {
            $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
              content: 'Uploading QC...',
              showBackdrop: false
            });
            var options = {
              fileKey: "image",
              fileName: "test.png",
              chunkedMode: true,
              mimeType: "image/png",
              headers: {'x-auth-token': token},
              params: {'questionId': image.questionId}
            };
            return $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(MOBILEAPP_URL + "file/upload", image.image, options);
          });
          return $q.all(images).then(lastTask);

          function lastTask(results) {
            results.forEach(function (result) {
              row.doc.qc.image.push(JSON.parse(result.response));
            });

            $http({
              method: 'POST', url: MOBILEAPP_URL + 'api/forms/qualitycontrol', headers: {
                'x-auth-token': token
              }, data: row.doc.qc
            }).
              success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.qc = {image: []};
                $scope.sigImg = '';
                $scope.images.test.length = 0;
                $scope.images.length = 0;
              }).
              error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.showAlert('error ' + status);
              }).
              finally(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $scope.showAlert('QC successfully saved!');
                $scope.localQcDB.destroy().then(function () {
                  $scope.localQcDB = new PouchDB("offline_qcs");
                }).catch(function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                });
              });
          }
        });
        return $q.all(rows);
      });
    };
```